# Entity Framework - Generic Transaction Methods

Tags: entity-framework, transactions

We're currently using transactions with the Entity Framework, but might be switching to some other ORM in the future.  What's the best way to implement the following...

```
BeginTransaction();

//Some update/insert/delete operations here
entity.Name = "Joe";
SaveChanges();

EndTransaction();
```

- We don't want to use the "using" statement
- We need it to work with nested transactions

Comment: you don't have to use "using" just make sure you dispose of all the transactions

Comment: **Why** are you set against using `using` ?? Any particular reason??

Comment: We want to conditionally use them in some instances, and we're thinking that generic methods will be more portable.  We've tried creating the TransactionScope in BeginTranaction() and completing/disposing of it in EndTransaction(), but that does not work either.  This could be an issue with the Entity Framework though.   For now, it looks like will need to stick with USING.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use TransactionScope ... and you can nest it in a try/catch/finally if you REALLY want to, though the "using" statement would be easier.  Is there any specific reason you don't want to use "using"?  I've used both together with quite some success, and it supports nested transactions.

1. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.transactions.transactionscope.aspx
2. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738523.aspx

Comment: Yes, we didn't won't to use the "using" statement for a few reasons, conditional transactions, portability, plus too many nested levels can get messy sometimes.  We did figure that we can simple use the TransactionScope in the BeginTransaction() method, then simply complete and dispose of it in the EndTransaction() method.  We were having a problem with EF and our driver before.